# Horizontally centering div and span with input child

Tags: html, css

I need this input field to prepend a # before the hex colour code, like so, as well as horizontally center both the div and the span containers:

```
<div id="color_wrapper">
    <span>#<input type="text" value="ffffff"></span>    
</div>
```

When I try with the following css:

```css
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#fff
}

#color_wrapper{
    border: none;
    background-color:#444;
    text-align:center;
}

span, input {
    border: none;
}

input{
    outline:none;
    width:85px;
    background-color:transparent;
    font-size:inherit;
    color:inherit;
    display:inherit;
}
```

I achieve limited success, in that the hash is at the start and the span and input seem to be centered. The problem occurs when I attempt to set the width of the div, and though the width is set, it snaps back to the left.

So, how can I center the div and the span, while also being able to change the div's width?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u8p5rw43/1/)'s a fiddle with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify `margin: 0 auto` for your div.

```css
html body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-size:22px;
 color:#fff
}

#color_wrapper{
  width:300px;
 border: none;
 background-color:#444444;
 text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
 
span, input {
    border: none;
}

input{
 outline:none;
 width:85px;
 background-color:transparent;
 font-size:inherit;
 color:inherit;
 display:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="color_wrapper">
 <span>#<input type="text" value="ffffff"></span> 
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
span,input
{
 align:center;
}
```

Hope it helps :-)